# What does countably many signify?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Consider the following definition of discrete Random Variable from the book titled [All of Statistics: A Concise Course in Statistical Inference](https://www.amazon.in/All-Statistics-Statistical-Inference-Springer/dp/0387402721)

> X is discrete if it takes countably **many** values

What the word **many** says in the definition? Consider the following

> X is discrete if it takes countable set

I hope the above statement is true. Does the word many says that there should be multiple values?

Comment: The first statement is better grammar.  It means that the number of values take is countable. The second would mean that the individual values are themselves countable, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you familiar with the difference between [countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set) and *uncountable*? As in comparing two kinds of infinities. Anyway, I'm fairly sure that the phrase *countably many* is used here to exclude the possibility of $X$ taking *uncountably many* values. Like a full interval of real numbers.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yeah. Familiar. But just confused with the word **many** here. Why not less and countable....

Comment: @saulspatz Edited....

Comment: It means $X$ takes a countable number of values. "takes countable set" is not something a fluent English speaker would write.

Comment: The word many does not signify more than one.  If it is constant, it takes countably many values.

Comment: Oh. It is about English as opposed to Math. May be this question should be migrated to the sister [English Language Learners.SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions)?

Answer (score 6):

It's standard English grammar.

You would say, for instance, that a set has extremely many elements, or that a function takes remarkably many values (not that that has any formal mathematical meaning). "Countably" works in exactly the same way grammatically as "extremely" and "remarkably".

Answer (score 3):

In English, "X-ly many" means the same thing as "an X number of", where X can be a wide variety of adjectives.  So "countably many" means exactly the same thing as "a countable number of".  It doesn't mean there actually literally are "many"; there could be none, or just one (since an empty set or singleton set is still a countable set).

Your proposed phrasing "it takes countable set" is not grammatical English since the noun phrase "countable set" requires a [determiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners).  If you instead said "it takes a countable set" that would be grammatical but would be unclear: what does it mean for a random value to "take" a set?  The correct way to use a phrasing along these lines would be "it takes a countable set of values".

Comment: Or perhaps “it takes values in a countable set”.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I would say that typically has a different meaning: that would mean the codomain is countable, rather than that the image is countable.  Of course if you don't consider the codomain to be intrinsic to the function then it is no difference since a subset of a countable set is countable.  But for instance, "it takes values in an uncountable set" would not mean that it has to actually take uncountably many different values.